# Does second answer count as first when first answer was deleted?

Tags: support

Just out of idle edge case curiosity during coffee break:

Does an answer that was posted second count as a first answer towards the "Enlightened" badge when the first answer was deleted?

Comment: By "first" do you mean "accepted" answer ?

Comment: No, literally "first" as required for the "enlightened" badge. http://stackoverflow.com/badges/19/enlightened

Answer (score 4):

Yes it does, but if the "first" answer is undeleted later on, then you lose your "first" status.

This can affect the validity of the Enlightened badge. If you later become eligible for another Enlightened badge and you "un-earned" the first one, you won't be given another one.

Comment: +1 - I've got an Enlightened badge from a second answer when the first was deleted. I haven't checked (as I can't remember which answer it was) to see if the other answer is still deleted.

Comment: I have had the same experience.

Answer (score 2):

I guess not; the first answer, though "deleted", it still exists.

It's not actually deleted from the database, it's soft deleted (you just don't see it anymore).

If that makes the second count as the first, I don't know, I'll let Jeff confirm it.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with downvoter, I don't think so too.

Let's say first answer is deleted, second answer become first, then got a Enlightened badge with 10 upvotes.

Then "real" first answer edited with new content and got undeleted, also got 10 upvotes, so there will be 2 answers Enlightened?

So, probably its not.